# the method 'map' was called on null. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get user from Json,but somehow i get en error that says

```
the method 'map' was called on null. flutter
```

I don't know why,here are my codes for my models:

```
class User {

  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String username;
   List<FollowUserModel> following = [];
   List<FollowUserModel> followers = [];
  
  User({this.id,this.email,this.followers,this.following, this.username});

  factory User.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {

    return User(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      email: jsonMap['email'] as String,
       username: jsonMap['username'] as String,
      following: jsonMap["following_set"] != null ? List<FollowUserModel>.from( jsonMap["followiing_set"].map((x) => FollowUserModel.fromJSON(x))) :[],
      followers: jsonMap["followers_set"] != null ? List<FollowUserModel>.from( jsonMap["followers_set"].map((x) => FollowUserModel.fromJSON(x))) :[],
     );
  }
}

class FollowUserModel {
  final String id;
  final User author;
  final User profile;


  FollowUserModel({this.id,this.author,this.profile});


  factory  FollowUserModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return  FollowUserModel(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      author: jsonMap['author'] as User,
      profile: jsonMap['profile'] as User,
    );
  }



}
```

And here is my full error code from my exception:
[image: Exception Code]

I declared the arrays as [] before as i expect some null returns but still,i get the error. Anybody knows the reason?

**Update**
I know i made typo,but still the error exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You made typos, instead of 'following_set' and 'followers_set' you have written 'followiing_set' and 'followrse_set':

```
.... 
following: jsonMap["following_set"] != null ? List<FollowUserModel>.from( jsonMap["followiing_set"].map((x) => FollowUserModel.fromJSON(x))) :[],
followers: jsonMap["followers_set"] != null ? List<FollowUserModel>.from( jsonMap["followrse_set"].map((x) => FollowUserModel.fromJSON(x))) :[],
....
```